# For loop to find files of largest size and copy them to another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ls, cp

I am trying to create a loop to sort files within each of many directories by size, then copy the largest two to another location, keeping the directory format (below).

```
folder/sample 1  
       .../s1.fastq.gz  
       .../s2.fastq.gz  
       .../s3.fastq.gz  
       .../s4.fastq.gz  
folder/sample 2  
       .../s1.fastq.gz  
       .../s2.fastq.gz  
       .../s3.fastq.gz  
       .../s4.fastq.gz
```

I'm new to Linux, so I'm struggling. I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir newfolder

for dir in folder/*
do
echo $dir
ls -S $dir/*.gz | head -n +2 | cp -T newfolder

done
```

However, I get the following error.

```
cp: missing destination file operand after 'newfolder.'
```

How do I correctly feed the large files into the copy function?

I've also tried using xargs, but I get the error

```
xargs: invalid option -- 'w'
```

because I am not correctly feeding in one line at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command once per line of piped input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input)

Comment: Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321757/70524

Comment: If you can use the `zsh` shell: `cp *.fastq.gz(.OL[1,2]) newfolder` in each directory.

Comment: Could you consider using a shell other than `bash` to solve the issue?

Comment: @Łukasz, *please* be careful with your edits, don’t change commands etc. (`newfolder` to `new folder` here, it introduces another error).

Comment: Thanks all! 
I cannot use `zsh` as I am executing this on a cluster/server that only operates `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` would be a much better choice of shell for that than `bash`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
for dir (folder/*(/)) {
  two_largest_files=($dir/*.gz(N.OL[1,2]))
  if (($#two_largest_files)) {
    mkdir -p newfolder/$dir:t &&
      cp -v $two_largest_files newfolder/$dir:t/ || ret=$?
  }
}
exit $ret
```

(note that `-v`, for verbose is not supported by all `cp` implementations, replace with `(set -x; cp $two...)` if yours doesn't support it).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Never, ever try to parse the output of `ls`, use `stat` instead;
2. When files are "many", or filenames contain "funny" characters ("`/sample 1/`") use `find` and `xargs`. Refer to `man find` and `man xargs` for further info.

Do something like:

```
mkdir newdir

find . -type f -name '*.gz' -print0 |\
  xargs -0 -r stat --printf="%s:%N" |\
  sort -rn |\
  head -n 2 |\
  cut -d: -f 2 |\
  xargs cp -T newdir
```

Warning! Untested code (I'm on phone). Replace the last line with

```
xargs echo cp -T newdir
```

Until it works.

For the curious, see [https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs](http://Parsing%20'ls')

Comment: You're using nul-delimiters only part of the way through that pipeline, but drop them for `sort`. There is no need to escape the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complex. First, you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`, as for files with newlines in their names things can get messy. So it's best to use the NUL as record (line) delimiter in all the pipeline. This is an example:

```
for dir in folder/*
do
    echo "$dir"
    find "$dir" -type f -print0 -exec du -h0 {} + | sort -hrz | head -zn 2 |
        sed -z 's/^.*[[:space:]]// ' | xargs -0I@ cp -v @ newfolder
done
```

1. `find` finds the files in the given `"$dir"` - you should use the quotes here. It also applies `du` to all the files to get their size.
2. `sort` sorts the results by size.
3. `head` limits to top 2.
4. `sed` gets rid of the size value before the file name.
5. `xargs` builds the actual command using the arguments from the pipeline.

NUL delimiter has normally to be indicated in all commands, and so there are the `z` flags in `sort`, `head` and `sed`; `0` in `du` and `xargs`; and they're produced by the `-print0` switch of `find`.

(I don't know why you use the `-T` flag in `cp`. In my example it's not there, and there's `-v` instead to give feedback.)