# How to loop netcat for each line of input?

Tags: awk, syslog, netcat

I am trying to send text log files to my remote syslog server. I need to be able to take a file, and for each line in that file (newline as the separator), send that line via `netcat` to a remote syslog host. I don't want the whole file to be sent in one connection as it will show in syslog as one massive blob. Also, I need to be able to execute this from the command line. I can't create a script and execute it.

For example, this sends the whole file in one blob (not what I want):

```
cat somemultilinefile | nc -u -w 0 syslogip 514
```

I have tried `awk` with `system()` and `xargs`, but have not found a combination that works. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command once per line of piped input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input)

Answer (score 0):

So I have found this works:

cat somemultilinefile | while read -r line; do echo "$line" | nc -w0 -u syslog_server 514 ; done

Seems that there should be a better way but this gets it done.

Comment: There is a better way, check the `rsyslog` module [RELP](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omrelp.html).