# Looping through variables which is an output of another command

Tags: shell-script, for, read

Hello I am learning Scripting here. I am trying to write a simple script using the 'for' loop.

I have hundreds of folders in a folder called user.
if i run this command i get a list of folders that i need to move to another folder

```
cat failed | awk -F ":" '/FAILED/ {print $1}' |  uniq
```

i.e folders under users that have failed a task have to be moved to users/failed/failedusers

what i am currently doing is i am creating a new file first using

```
cat failed | awk -F ":" '/FAILED/ {print $1}' |  uniq > failedusers
```

and then i move the folders using the following command

```
while read line; do cp -r users/$line users/failed; done < failedusers
```

My question here is can i do the same using just the **for** command instead of writing the output to another file and using the **while read** command to get it done?

for example somehow assign a value to a variable in a loop like

```
faileduser=`cat failed | awk -F ":" '/FAILED/ {print $1}' |  uniq`
```

and then write something like

```
mv users/$faileduser user/failed/$faileduser
```

i am getting all kinds of errors when i am trying to write something like above.

thanks

Comment: Not sure how a `for` comes into the picture, but do you mean something like `cat failed | awk -F ":" '/FAILED/ {print $1}' |  uniq | while read line; do cp -r users/$line users/failed; done < failedusers`? If so you could use `xargs` with `cp` instead of using `while` + `read` +`cp`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command once per line of piped input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `xargs` and a shell with support for ksh-style process substitution, you can do:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -I USER -a <(awk -F : '/FAILED/ {print $1}' failed | sort -u
  ) cp -r users/USER user/failed/USER
```

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
faileduser=( ${(f)"$(awk -F : '/FAILED/ {print $1}' failed | sort -u)"} )
autoload zargs
zargs -rI USER -- $faileduser -- cp -r users/USER user/failed/USER
```

Assuming you want to copy `USER` *to* `user/failed/USER`, that is, copy it *into* `user/failed`, you could also do (still with `zsh`):

```
(( $#faileduser )) && cp -r users/$^faileduser user/failed/
```

With the `bash` shell, you could do something similar with:

```
readarray -t faileduser < <(awk -F : '/FAILED/ {print $1}' failed | sort -u)
(( ${#faileduser[@]} )) &&
  cp -r "${faileduser[@]/#/user\/}" user/failed/
```

Or get `awk` to prepend the `user/` to all the user names:

```
readarray -t faileduser < <(awk -F : '/FAILED/ {print "user/"$1}' failed | sort -u)
(( ${#faileduser[@]} )) &&
  cp -r "${faileduser[@]}" user/failed/
```

With a `for` loop, with Korn-like shells (including `bash`, and would also work with `zsh`) the syntax would be:

```
for user in "${faileduser[@]}"; do
  cp -r "user/$user" "user/failed/$user"
done
```

Which in `zsh` could be shortened to:

```
for user ($faileduser) cp -r user/$user user/failed/$user
```

With:

> ```
> faileduser=`cat failed | awk -F ":" '/FAILED/ {print $1}' |  uniq`
> ```

(`` `...` `` being the archaic and deprecated form of command substitution. Use `$(...)` instead).

You're storing `awk`'s output in a *scalar*, not array variable.

In `zsh`, you can split it on newline with the `f` parameter expansion flag like we do directly above on the command substitution:

```
array=( ${(f)faileduser} )
```

In bash (or ksh), you could use the split+glob operator after having disabled glob and tuned split:

```
set -o noglob
IFS=$'\n'
array=( $faileduser )
```

(yes, in `bash`, leaving a parameter expansion unquoted invokes an implicit split+glob operator (!), a misfeature inherited from the Bourne shell, fixed in zsh and most modern non-Bourne-like shells).

Comment: so it seems i need to read up on read arrays in bash. Thanks.